# bootstrap menu with click and reveal drop down for screen sizes 768 px and 1099

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap for a drop down menu, and currently if screen sizes is more than 768 px; the drop down occurs when you hover mouse and if it goes below 768PX dropdown occurs when you click the menu item. its perfect.

But i want that from screen-size 768-1099px, it should be not hovering. It should be clicked and drop menu should appear as mobile version.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TutorialsPoint</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">iOS</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">SVN</a></li>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               Java <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">jmeter</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">EJB</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Jasper Report</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I didn't understand whats the problem, please explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily: http://www.bootply.com/114896

Just wrap that CSS in whatever sized media query you want to target, for example:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1099px) {
    .navbar-header {
      float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
      display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
      float: none!important;
      margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think part of the OPs issue is they dont know what CSS to wrap in that media query to make it work.

Comment: I clarified my answer.

Comment: not working, its only collapsing the menu, but drop down is still hovering, but less than 768 px its collapsing also and menu item are being clicked to see the dropdown, i want that way @Patrick